# Need to calculate time for which loading spinner is visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-applications, spinner

I am testing an application in which when we click few buttons then some http is sent in the backend and on ui a spinning loader comes. Using selenium java I need to calculate the time for which spinner is visible. The loading spinner has no xpath or css.

Comment: what happens after invisibility of spinning loader ?

Comment: It's a form. You click a button, spinner comes when it's validating something in the backend and then the spinner disappears so you can continue with the form. Same goes for submit button. On submitting, spinner comes for 1-2 seconds and then the next webpage loads up.

Comment: That’s fine ! Why do you wanna calculate the time ? Your usecase please ?

Comment: The performance team calculates the time for the http request that is sent when the spinner comes. I need to calculate the time till the spinner is visible to match it with performance team.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, the loading spinner is the mouse pointer indicating the application is processing the current request. If that is the case, try the below the solution

Applications can set the css property cursor of the body element to wait when processing a request, you can use that information to calculate the timing

you may have to convert to java

```
import time
start_time = time.time()  
While True:
    cursor_status = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')..value_of_css_property('cursor')
    if cursor_status != 'wait':
        break
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```